# Jackson - JPA entities

Tags: jpa, jackson

I want to avoid using proprietary Jackson annotations on my JPA entities, but need to serialize them.  If I do, I will run into an exception because my a parent is referenced through the child causing a cycle.

Are there any alternatives to marking up my entities, could Jackson be configured to look at the JPA annotations and ignore ones with a mappedBy property?  Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: why do you want to avoid using proprietary Jackson annotations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any ways to directly ask Jackson to ignore the the recursive without annotations. But if you want to force him to ignore any fields with a special annotation you could write some custom serializer in addition of reflection to avoid them.

http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html